# How to use a template in html with make?

Tags: html, makefile, gnu-make

I have a help file which must be translated into three languages.  This file contains technical informations which must be the same for the three languages.

I would like to use make file to create thoses help file from a config file (same for all the languages) and one template per language.

```
# Makefile
%.html: %.template data
    do somthing $< data > $@
```

Which template engine should I use to have the maximum indpendance against the platform used?

Thank you for your advices/opinions.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to have anything at all with make or makefiles.  I have no idea what you mean when you refer to _template engine_.  Perhaps if you provided some examples and tagged your question for those engines you'd have better answers.